# VB.NET 2010 Treeview

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a form with a Treeview control, I add first node pragmatically, when I add the second node the first node gets selected automatically! How to stop that, I dont need any node to be selected unless I select it.

The code i use:

```
        Dim Scr As New TreeNode()
        Scr.Text = ObjScreen.ScreenDescription
        Scr.Tag =  ObjScreen
        Scr.SelectedImageIndex = 0
        Scr.ImageIndex = 0

        tvScreens.Nodes.Add(Scr)
```

Comment: I can't repro. Can you provide the code you are using to add the nodes?

Comment: Perhaps show us your code so that we can follow what is happening?

Comment: TreeView strongly dislikes having a unselected node and will always select one by itself when it gets the focus. The first one unless you convince it otherwise by assigning the SelectedNode property.  A somewhat necessary evil because the blue highlight does double duty, it shows both that the TreeView has the focus *and* indicates the current node.  It does not have a way to intentionally unselect anything so you can stop looking for that solution.

Comment: I've tried by targeting .NET 2.0 and 4.6.1 and can't repro in either.

Comment: To Repro, create a form with treeview, and open a form to get the data from, after closing that form add the node to the treeview, repeat that twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
    Dim Activator as boolean
    Private Sub TreeView_BeforeSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles TreeView.BeforeSelect
    If Activator Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End if
    End Sub
```

Just set activator to true at the beginning of your code that adds nodes, and false it at the end.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but bare in mind that this code won't allow the OP to select _any_ node. You might want to add something that only sets `e.Cancel` when the OP is adding new nodes.

Comment: True true, a boolean variable while hes adding stuff should do it.

Comment: Actually you can even shorten it to: `e.Cancel = Activator` :)